# Should I answer my question

Tags: discussion, answers

Since posting a question I discovered AN answer (basically re-read the recipe!!) and posted a comment to that effect; hoping that others would give their opinion on the topic (for or against what the recipe said).
There have been no other replies, should I post my comment as an answer and mark the question as answered?
This is the question:
[which-type-of-charger-for-soda-syphon-batter](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/100017/which-type-of-charger-for-soda-syphon-batter)

Comment: Check also [ask], [answer] and the [tour] to learn more about the site.

Answer (score 5):

Yes! *Please* answer your own question! That is encouraged behavior on Stack Exchange. There are all kinds of reasons you might choose to answer your own question, and it's perfectly OK to do so.